# Web API 2 with Elmah - How to log exceptions outside actions?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, exception, asp.net-web-api2, elmah

I am using Web API 2 with Elmah, and I want to Elmah to catch exceptions that occur **outside of actions in controllers**.

For example in:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{ 
    //Exception is thrown here. I want Elmah to catch it.
}
```

and in Startup.Auth.cs:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    //Exception is thrown here. I want Elmah to catch it.
}
```

- Elmah version is 1.2.2
- I am using [Elmah.Contrib.WebApi](https://github.com/rdingwall/elmah-contrib-webapi)

Is there a reason Elmah.Contrib.WebApi catches exceptions only from within actions?

And if it's by desgin, are there any other ways, not using the contrib library, to catch exceptions outside actions?